# Why is one of my aspx TextBox values not transfering to my C# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASPX webform that takes some data and just sends an email.  It has worked for years but I just added a new field and I can't get the Text value to transfer to the c# code that writes the email.

The difference is that the new field is populated through jQuery/JSON look-up and it is read-only.  The jQuery portion is working fine.

TextBox in question:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="autoRegion" Width="30" ReadOnly="true" onfocus="this.blur();" TabIndex="-1" CssClass="disabledInput" Value="" runat="server" />
```

Working TextBoxes:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="FName" MaxLength="40" TabIndex="1" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="LName" MaxLength="40" TabIndex="3" runat="server" />
```

C# variable for email body content:

```
objMM.Body += "<table><tr><td>" + 
     LName.Text + "</td><td>" + FName.Text.ToUpper() + "</td><td>" +
     streetAddress1.Text + "</td><td>" + city.Text.ToUpper() + "</td><td>" +
     state.SelectedItem.Text + "</td><td>" + zip.Text + "</td><td>" + autoRegion.Text +
     "</td></tr></table>";
```

All other fields are working but `autoRegion.Text` is not.

I have also tried filling a variable with `Request.Form["autoRegion"]` and using that variable in place of `autoRegion.Text` but that did not work either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange behavior using HTML 'readonly="readonly"' vs. JavaScript 'element.readOnly = true;'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060518/strange-behavior-using-html-readonly-readonly-vs-javascript-element-readon)

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, read only items do not have their values posted back to the server since there would be no reason since they cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link: [ASP.NET textbox losing value after postback when value is changed client-side via javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922387/asp-net-textbox-losing-value-after-postback-when-value-is-changed-client-side-vi).  It appears that the postback only pushes the ViewState data for a TextBox that is either Disabled or ReadOnly.  Because you are loading the value via client-side, there is nothing in the ViewState for your TextBox.

There are several different work-around, but I would attempting the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570652/how-to-keep-the-text-of-a-read-only-textbox-after-post-back):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
}
```

In addition to applying this code, you would need to remove the ReadOnly="true" property from the TextBox on the aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

Mark Fitzpatrick is right, the problem is you are setting that TextBox to ReadOnly, which means its value is not persisted in ViewState.

Here is a potential workaround: [Disabled textbox losses viewstate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316399/disabled-textbox-losses-viewstate)

Edit: Also [Strange behavior using HTML 'readonly="readonly"' vs. JavaScript 'element.readOnly = true;'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060518/strange-behavior-using-html-readonly-readonly-vs-javascript-element-readon/1063609#1063609)

Answer (score 0):

Your should do some changes

1. remove read only property in textbox as given below

   2. this propety add on page load as given below
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
      autoRegion.Attributes.Add("readonly","readonly");
      }